# Compose TV scrolling with D-PAD

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I have this code

```
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
    columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(
        top = 16.dp,
        end = 12.dp,
        bottom = 16.dp,
    ),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    verticalItemSpacing = 16.dp,
    userScrollEnabled = true,
) {
    item {
        data.moreInformationText?.let { morInformationText ->
            Text(
                text = morInformationText,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(
                    color = Color(context.partnerTheme.themePrimaryTint0),
                ),
            )
        }
    }
```

The problem is that scrolling with mouse is working but since this is a TV the scrolling with the D-pad doesn't work.

The moreinformationText is really long so we need to scroll that.

I've tried to use simply a

```
Column {
        Text(
            text = data.moreInformationText!!,
            modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        )
    }
```

Without any grid but still didn't work.

Comment: On a TV, users primarily interact with D-PAD. Using D-PAD, you move focus from 1 item to another. Because your text is not focusable, D-PAD cannot move focus anywhere and hence nothing is scrolling. You probably want to add some focusable items on the screen like buttons, cards, etc. On a side note, displaying very long text on a TV is not a good UX. You should probably look for some alternative design.

Comment: I tried to make text focusable nothing changed.....

Comment: If it is a huge block of text, it still won't be scrollable. I meant to say, break your text into smaller text chunks and make each of those chunks as focusable. That way, you can jump from one focusable chunk to another chunk.

Answer (score 0):

On a TV, users primarily interact with D-PAD. Using D-PAD, you move focus from 1 item to another. Because your text is not focusable, D-PAD cannot move focus anywhere and hence nothing is scrolling. You probably want to add some focusable items on the screen like buttons, cards, etc. On a side note, displaying very long text on a TV is not a good UX. You should probably look for some alternative design.

If you still want to have long block of text, you can choose to do the following:

1. Break down the text into smaller chunks and make each of the chunk a separate focusable Text component. Wrap it in a scrollable container.

```
LazyColumn {
  item {
    Text("Chunk 1", Modifider.focusable())
  }
  item {
    Text("Chunk 2", Modifider.focusable())
  }
  ...
}
```

2. Make use of the `onKeyEvent` modifier to listen to key events on the long text block and using this, programmatically scroll the container as shown below.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTvMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun App() {
    val someHugeText = (1..10000).joinToString(" ")
    val scrollAmount = 100f
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val cs = rememberCoroutineScope()

    fun scroll(reverse: Boolean = false) {
        cs.launch {
            scrollState.scrollBy(if (reverse) -scrollAmount else scrollAmount)
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
            .onKeyEvent {
                if (it.nativeKeyEvent.action == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    return@onKeyEvent KeyEventPropagation.ContinuePropagation
                }
                if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
                    scroll(false)
                    return@onKeyEvent KeyEventPropagation.StopPropagation
                }
                if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
                    scroll(true)
                    return@onKeyEvent KeyEventPropagation.StopPropagation
                }
                return@onKeyEvent KeyEventPropagation.ContinuePropagation
            }
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .clickable {
                println("Pikachu: scrollState value=${scrollState.value} maxValue=${scrollState.maxValue}")
            }
        ,
    ) {
        Text(text = someHugeText)
    }
}

internal object KeyEventPropagation {
    const val StopPropagation = true
    const val ContinuePropagation = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just one sidenote I didn't find the KeyEventPropagation so simply changed the `KeyEventPropagation.StopPropagation` to false and `KeyEventPropagation.ContinuePropagation` to true

Comment: It is at the very bottom.

Comment: ah sorry thanks I've missed it :).